# JSON Stringify Unable to decode value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm having one big trouble.

When I send post request with angular, and do JSON.Stringify it returns (unable to decode value). I don't know how to solve it

[image]

Comment: I've often found that typing "var tmp = <insertJsonStringHere>;" into the console of Chrome to be helpful, since it shows me where the problem lies. Failing that, there's online JSON validation thinga-ma-bobs

Comment: what data did you expect?

Comment: Do you stringify the object before sending it via `$http` or `$resource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular.toJson() method instead. Because some internal notation are used by angularjs.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

> Serializes input into a JSON-formatted string. Properties with leading
>   $$ characters will be stripped since angular uses this notation
>   internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error of malformed JSON , you are getting this error cause you are using **POST** along with the following Request Header : (**"Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**). In that case you will have to use **encodeURIComponent()** along with **JSON.stringify()** on your JSON Object in order not to get the above error.

If your Request Header is ("Content-Type","application/json") you do not need to use encodeURIComponent() , simply using **JSON.stringify**() is sufficient.

**Note** : You could also use **GET** and wouldn't get the error , but **GET** has length limitations in your message and is usually avoided when sending JSON)